# Same size for all MudItem using MudBlazor

Tags: .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I'm trying in **MudBlazor** to make e-commerce style boxes where you can view image, product name and other information.

I am currently using the `MudGrid` with the related `MudItem`.
See this example:

[image: Problem displaying items in the grid]

As you can see the height of the various `MudItem` is not the same for all, but it adapts according to the size of the image.
I would like the `MudItem` to be all the same high and that they remain responsive (depending on the display device)

You can find the code here: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GaGcYmmFziEpEAPJ

Comment: The link you posted does not work for me. You will most likely need to add custom CSS to your page to override the CSS from MudBlazor. Give the element containing the image a fixed height, and set the image to scale to that container.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same issue, you need to do the following:

```
<MudGrid>
        <MudItem Style="display:flex;"> each card </MudItem>
        <MudItem Style="display:flex;"> each card </MudItem>
        <MudItem Style="display:flex;"> each card </MudItem>
</MudGrid>
```

Then you can adjust the content of each card. Also to avoid calling style everytime you could inject some css with one class.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish this by setting the MudItem style to display:flex and setting the MudCardContent  style to min-height: 100px (in my case)

```
<MudPaper Width="100%" Class="darkbackground" MinHeight="350">
<MudContainer>
    <MudGrid>
        <MudItem xs="4" Style="display:flex;">
            <MudPaper Width="100%" Square="false" Class="pa-10 ma-2 infobox" Outlined="true">
                <MudCard>
                    <MudCardMedia Image="/images/rm/rm1.png" Height="200" />
                    <MudCardContent Style="min-height: 100px">
                        <MudText Class="textwhite" Typo="Typo.subtitle1">Always Evolving</MudText>
                        <MudText Class="textsilver" Typo="Typo.body2">Creating innovative new ways to trade the exchange markets</MudText>
                    </MudCardContent>
                </MudCard>
            </MudPaper>
        </MudItem>
        <MudItem xs="4" Style="display:flex;">
            <MudPaper Width="100%" Square="false" Class="pa-10 ma-2 infobox" Outlined="true">
                <MudCard>
                    <MudCardMedia Image="/images/rm/rm2.png" Height="200" />
                    <MudCardContent Style="min-height: 100px">
                        <MudText Class="textwhite" Typo="Typo.subtitle1">Is RainMaker Open Source?</MudText>
                        <MudText Class="textsilver" Typo="Typo.body2">RainMaker is not open source. Currently just a passion project</MudText>
                    </MudCardContent>
                </MudCard>
            </MudPaper>
        </MudItem>
        <MudItem xs="4" Style="display:flex;">
            <MudPaper Width="100%" Square="false" Class="pa-10 ma-2 infobox" Outlined="true">
                <MudCard>
                    <MudCardMedia Image="/images/rm/rm3.png" Height="200" />
                    <MudCardContent Style="min-height: 100px">
                        <MudText Class="textwhite" Typo="Typo.subtitle1">What is required to trade?</MudText>
                        <MudText Class="textsilver" Typo="Typo.body2">A broker account with Oanda.</MudText>
                    </MudCardContent>
                </MudCard>
            </MudPaper>
        </MudItem>
</MudGrid>
</MudContainer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from adding `Style="display: flex;"` to the `MudItem`, if you want the buttons to be at the bottom as well add

`Style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; width 100%;"`

to each `MudCard` and

`Class="mt-auto"`

to each `MudCardAction`